# how to replace item in row with another item located in different row based on column item

Tags: python, csv

I have .csv file with many rows and a few columns. I want to get rows where some items replaced with items located at another row based on value of under some column.

How I can do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.